# Force nvidia videowall (surround) settings

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a videowall, consisting of 4x 1080p displays which are managed as a nvidia surround desktop, which works very well. My Problem is only, that if e.g. one display losses the connection (which unfortunately happens quite often), and the computer gets restarted with e.g. 3 Displays, the configuration gets lost.

Can anyone tell me a solution to force the driver to always use my 4x1080p display configuration, so that e.g. the missing display is just black, but the positions are the same.

The operating system is Windows 7.